# Error in wrting file in servlet

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets

I have created a file from the doPost Method in servlet but I am unable to write the data to it. I could not figured out what is the error. By the way the file is creating

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        response.getWriter().println(name);
        File filename= new File("/home/ksampath/D3/DedupeEngine/cache3.txt");
        filename.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("I am going to create a new file");
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("cache3.txt",true);
            out=new BufferedWriter(fw);
            out.write("hello world");
            out.write(name);
        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error"+ e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if(out!=null)
            {
                out.close();
            }
        }
        /*
        System.out.println("Lets us check whether it works");
        PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<h3>hello This is my first servlet</h3>");*/
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting exception or compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(filename,true);   //where filename is that File object
```

> **public FileWriter(File file,
>             boolean append)
>              throws IOException**
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second
>   argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file
>   rather than the beginning.

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by @singhakash is correct.

You can either use

```
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(filename,true);
```

and as stated that if second argument is true than bytes will be appended at end.

or you can use `getAbsoluteFile()`method of File, in this way

```
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(filename.getAbsoluteFile());
```

> The `getAbsoluteFile()`method will return, The absolute abstract
>   pathname denoting the same file or directory as this abstract pathname([JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile%28%29))